# How to make binary image more clearly to improve accuracy tesseract image_to_text?

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I'm having an image like this:

[image]

Then i convert to binary image, then dilate it, will return result like this:
[image]

But there is still having something related between the characters and it cause the wrong result when i call `tesseract.image_to_text()` function. The result was `BO09804`, is there anyway to detach each character in image or apply some filters?

Here is my code:

```
    src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile('path/to/image.jpg'))
    src = image_resize(src, height=128, inter=cv.INTER_CUBIC)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rect, binary = cv.threshold(gray , 180, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU)
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    dilated = cv.dilate(binary, kernel, iterations=1)
    cv.imshow('dilated', dilated)
    cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: This isn’t very helpful, but the basic problem is the quality of your image; can you get a higher-resolution scan which doesn’t use jpeg compression?

Comment: I dont have another choice when the scanner machine give only jpg or jpeg :|

Answer (score 0):

I have done some opencv code to filter your image as much as I can. But of course if u could find a better resolution images will be much better.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
import pytesseract 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract"

image = cv2.imread("import tesseract.png",0)
image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(3,3),-1,-1)
_,thre = cv2.threshold(image,140,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
contors , _ = cv2.findContours(thre,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contors = sorted(contors,key= lambda b:cv2.contourArea(b),reverse=False)
mask = np.zeros_like(thre)
contors = [c for c in contors if cv2.contourArea(c)>100]
cv2.drawContours(mask,contors[:-1],-1,[255],-1)

# creating a mask
kerenal = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(1,20))
morpg = cv2.dilate(mask,kerenal,iterations=1)

_,thre = cv2.threshold(image,190,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# applying mask to thre image
img = cv2.bitwise_and(morpg,thre)
# add eroding to increase the space between characters 
kerenal = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(2,1))
morpg = cv2.erode(img,kerenal,iterations=1)
```

The mask image after dilate

[image]

image after bitwise_and

[image]

The filtered image is attached below

[image]

The tesseract results is

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(morpg).split("\n")[0]
```

The results is : 'B009864'

Comment: can u display the final image, does it look like mine ? Can u download the image from here and apply my code.

Comment: do you mean the image which i posted?

Comment: From the original image, it has size of ````3292 x 4665````, then i resize the image to ````(1010, 713)```` (returned from ````image.shape````) to make the ````HoughLinesP()```` work properly. then i tried to scale up image to make OCR, but i think b'cause of multiple time of resizing, it cause the descreasing of image resolution....

Comment: I think i got a trick, that i scale up image more larger after cropped, about ````700%```` for ````height```` and ````800%```` for ````width````

Comment: The image you posted here is of the size 440*128 you should use the exact size to get the same results as min.  In the code I posted some parameters you can tune them to make it work.

Comment: Can you tell me why the kernel for ````dilate```` is ````(1,20)```` and ````erode```` is ````(2,1)````

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you the image in some steps. Basically the dilate was to create a mask. The mask was to make sure each character is separated from the other.  The erode at the end is just to separate the character a little bit more.